# WordPress исчезает логотип на мобильной версии сайта при загрузке страницы

Tags: wordpress

Сайт написан на WP, использован бесплатный шаблон.
При загрузке сайта на мобильном устройстве логотип отображается на 1 секунду и сразу исчезает.
 
В адресе изображения появляется - @2x, и файл не грузится..
 
Такой становится ссылка - https://prom-torg@2x.spb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/logo.png 
Откуда берётся это - @2x? И как это убрать?

На полной версии сайта всё работает корректно и логотип не исчезает.

Весь инет перерыл ничего не нашел!

Comment: Есть у вас плагины для изображений под ретину?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или тема, или плагин, в js-коде пытаются заменить изображение логотипа другим, подготовленным под Retina. Такие изображения имеют разрешение вдвое выше обычного и получают суффикс @2x.

Плагин или тема предполагают, что ваши изображения для Retina будут размещены на поддомене prom-torg@2x.spb.ru. Но поддомен с таким именем существовать не может, символ `@` недопустим. Налицо плохой код, от которого надо избавиться.

Отключите все плагины по одному, смените тему на стандартную, чтобы найти источник такого кода. И не используйте его.

Comment: Удалил скрипты jQuery но не помогает. При инспекции страницы в разделе Network красным подсвечен файл logo.png и в графе initiator красным отмечено: jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4. При наведении курсора высвечивается окно с кучей ссылок на jquery. Я его весь из кода удалил но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, кроме того, что вы делаете не то, что я рекомендовал: отключать плагины по одному, менять тему на стандартную, чтобы понять источник проблемы.